# A generating function for a non-homogeneous linear Diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose we have an equation $a_1 x_1 + \ldots +a_k x_k = l$, where $a_i$ and $l$ are integers, but not necessarily non-negative. Moreover, assume not all $a_i$ are zero, and that $k$ is at least $2$.

Denote by $S$ the set of all its non-negative integer solutions $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$.

Consider the following generating function: $\displaystyle G(q) = \sum_{x \in S} q^{x_1+\ldots+x_k}$.

In other words, the coefficient of $G(q)$ next to $q^n$ is the number of non-negative solutions whose coordinates add upp to $n$.

- **Q1:** Is $G(q)$ a rational function of $q$? (By identifying it with its power series expansion.)
- **Q2:** If yes, is there a chance that there is a "common" denominator of $G(q)$ independent of the non-homogeneous parameter $l$?
- **Q3:** Is there a general method of finding $G(q)$ in a closed form as a rational function of $q$?

Any hint or reference related to this questions is appreciated.

Comment: If $k=1$ and $a_1=l=0$ then $G(q)$ is not a rational function, and then the following questions are moot. There are also examples that are less trivial.

Comment: More explicitly; your first question is equivalent to asking whether $\sum x_i$ is bounded. It is easy to construct many examples for which this is not the case. Take for example $k=2$ and $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1$ and $l=0$. Or $a_1=1$ and $a_2=0$ and any $l$.

Comment: Are you sure? In the case you give, $G(q) = \frac{1}{1-q^2}$.

Comment: By the way, even in the trivial case (cf. your first comment), $G(q) = 1 + q + q^2 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-q}$.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, you equate the rational function with its power series. That makes more sense. Then the question becomes whether the coefficients of $G(q)$ satisfy a linear recurrence (eventually).

Comment: OK, I will make this explicit.

Comment: Indeed $G(q)$ is rational. Rough idea: Arrange the $a_i$ in descending order and set $b_i:=a_i-a_k$ and $c_d:=l-da_k$ so that the $d$-th coefficient of $G(q)$ equals the number of solutions to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}b_ix_i=c_d.$$
This is precisely the $c_d$-th coefficient of $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{1-x^{b_i}}$, which is a rational function. An arithmetic subsequence of its coefficients then also defines a rational function, so in particular $G(q)$ is rational.

Comment: There is a gap, and I do not think it can be easily overcome. The coefficients of $G(q)$ are not the numbers of solutions to your $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} b_i x_i = c_d$; the last equation has more solutions. Namely, the equation does not "remember" that $d - x_1- \ldots - x_{k-1}$ must be non-negative in order to make a solution to the original problem.